# Angular JS breadcrumbs returning to home page with parametrs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breadcrumbs

I want to have breadcrumbs like :  Home / Cars / Audi / T8, where Home, Cars and Audi sends back to HomePage but with different parameters e.g. Cars checkbox clicked etc.

I use AngularJS with ui.router and ncy-angular-breadcrumb.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('main',{ 
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'HomePage'
        }
    })

    .state('main.type',{
        controller: function($scope, breadcrumbsFctry) {
            $scope.defaultType = 'car';
        },
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: '{{defaultType}}',  
            parent: 'main'
        }
    })

    .state('main.type.make',{
        controller: function($scope, breadcrumbsFctry) {
            $scope.defaultMake = 'audi';
        },
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: '{{defaultMake}}',
            parent: 'main.type'
        }
    })
    .state('car', {
        url: '/ad/:name-:id',
        templateUrl: 'views/ad/ad.html',
        controller: 'AdCtrl',
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: ':name',
            parent: 'main.type.make'
        }
    })
```

Factory :

```
.factory('breadcrumbsFctry', function () {

        var type = '';
        var make = '';

        return {

        };

    });
```

How share the parameters via states with different Controllers ?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the relevant data in a dedicated service, or use native JS storage services such as sessionStorage or localStorage.

Services are singletons and can be used to share data between controllers.

Read about sessionStorage and localStorage here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help in your situation but I have built breadcrumbs for my site using the standard `ngRoute` I have not used the ui-router so this might not apply however you can give it a go. I have setup some options in my routes like so:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    $routeProvider.

    when('/blog/:slug', {
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/blog/views/blog.single.view.html',
        controller: 'blog',
        label: 'postTitle' //this is dynamic /some-post-slug/that-matches-postTitle/
    }).

    when('/blog', {
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/blog/views/blog.index.view.html',
        controller: 'blog',
        label: 'blog'
    });

}]);
```

Then I have setup a custom factory and directive for the breadcrumbs:

```
app
    .factory('breadcrumbs', ['$rootScope', '$route', 'hitch', function ($rootScope, $route, hitch) {

        var service = {

            breadcrumbs: [],

            build: function() {

                //If active route
                if ($route.current && $route.current.originalPath) {

                    this.breadcrumbs = [];

                    var params = $route.current.params,
                        urlParts = $route.current.originalPath.split('/');

                    //Split up the path to get parent route /parent/child - [parent, parent/child]
                    angular.forEach(urlParts, hitch(this, function(part, index) {

                        var isParam = function(part){ //Test if this url part is a param
                                return part[0] === ':' && typeof params[part.substring(1)] !== 'undefined' ? params[part.substring(1)] : false;
                            },
                            pathWithParam = '', //Full route with param still intact as '/:param'
                            pathWithQuery = ''; //Full route with param as query '/someQuery'

                        //For each url part under this index
                        for(var i=0;i<=index;i++){

                            //Make path with params
                            pathWithParam += urlParts[i];

                            //Make path with query
                            if(isParam(urlParts[i])){
                                pathWithQuery += isParam(urlParts[i]);
                            } else {
                                pathWithQuery += urlParts[i];
                            }

                            //If not last in url add trailing slash
                            if(i !== index) { 
                                pathWithParam +='/';
                                pathWithQuery +='/';
                            }

                        }

                        //Make sure router and label exists for this part
                        if ($route.routes[pathWithParam] && ($route.routes[pathWithParam].label || param)) {
                            this.breadcrumbs.push({
                                path: pathWithQuery,
                                label: $route.routes[pathWithParam].label || param,
                                param: isParam(part)
                            });
                        }

                    }));

                }

            },

            //Improve this
            getDynamicLabel: function() {
                if (this.dynamicLabels) {
                    //Each label
                    for (var key in this.dynamicLabels) {
                        //Each breadcrumb
                        for (var index in this.breadcrumbs) {
                            //If using dynamic label set as label
                            var breadcrumb = this.breadcrumbs[index];
                            if (breadcrumb.label === key) {
                                breadcrumb.label = this.dynamicLabels[key];
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
                return this.breadcrumbs;
            }

        };

        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
            service.build();
        });

        $rootScope.$watch(function(){ return service.dynamicLabels; }, function() {
            service.build();
        });

        service.build();

        return service;

    }])
    .directive('breadcrumbs', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            template: '<ul class="breadcrumbs"><li ng-repeat="breadcrumb in breadcrumbs.getDynamicLabel() track by breadcrumb.path" ng-class="{ active: $last }"><a ng-if="!$last" ng-href="{{ breadcrumb.path }}" ng-bind="breadcrumb.label" class="margin-right-xs"></a> <span ng-if="!$last"> > </span><span ng-if="$last" ng-bind="breadcrumb.label"></span></li></ul>',
            replace: true
        };
    });
```

You can then use the breadcrumb directive in your view `<breadcrumbs></breadcrumbs>` which will track your current route as well as it's structure `route/route2/route3` you can also set dynamic labels by including the factory:

```
app.controller('blog', [
    '$scope', 
    '$routeParams', 
    'api', 
    'breadcrumbs', 
function($scope, $routeParams, api, breadcrumbs){

    api.blog.getPost({slug:$routeParams.slug}).then(function(response){
            breadcrumbs.dynamicLabels = {'postTitle': response.data.title};
        }, function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });

}]);
```